# How can I extract each of the first characters of a zip pair of strings in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
joinString = zip "aceg" "bdfh"
```

Becomes this after zipping: `[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g','h')]`. I want to extract the `'a' , 'c', 'e'` and `'g'` out from the list of tuples. How can I do that?

I tried `fst(unzip joinString)` but that gives me the string `"aceg"` but I want each and every of the characters individually.

Comment: What do you mean, individually? `"aceg"` and `['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']` are the *exact* same value, just displayed differently (because `String` is just a synonym for `[Char]`).

Comment: (That's why you can write `zip "aceg" "bdfh"` instead of `zip ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g'] ['b', 'd', 'f', 'h']` in the first place. `zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]`; it makes no assumptions about what kinds of lists it is dealing with.)

Comment: Can you show the value you want to get, notated in Haskell?

Comment: `"aceg" == ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']`, it's literally the same thing in Haskell

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, a string *is* a list of characters, so you have a misunderstanding, but also already the answer.

```
ghci> ['a', 'b', 'c'] == "abc"
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't have direct access to the parameters supplied to `zip`, you can use [map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:map) from `Data.List` to apply `fst` over every element of the zipped list:

```
ghci> map fst [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g','h')]
"aceg"
```

As pointed out already, `"aceg" == ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']`.